# UIKit UIImageView with Offset UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm currently adding a UIImageView to a Table Cell, and when the cell is populated with data, I'm adding a UIImage (if it exists) to the UIImageView, however, the UIImage is offset like this:

[image: Offset UIImage in UIImageView]

I'm using AutoLayout to setup the Cell, as follows:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CatalogItemTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let itemImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imgView.clipsToBounds = true
        imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: "FontColor")?.cgColor
        imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
        imgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        return imgView
    }()
    
    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        return label
    }()
    
    let skuLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    let descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        return label
    }()
    
    let qtyOnHand: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    let priceLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    let containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier);
        
        containerView.addSubview(itemImageView)
        containerView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(skuLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(qtyOnHand)
        containerView.addSubview(priceLabel)
        self.contentView.addSubview(containerView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
        [
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10.0),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10.0),
        ]);
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
        [
            itemImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            itemImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            itemImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -10),
            itemImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            itemImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
        ]);
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: skuLabel.topAnchor, constant: -10)
        ]);
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            skuLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            skuLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.leadingAnchor),
            skuLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionLabel.topAnchor, constant: -10)
        ]);
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: skuLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -10.0),
            descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: skuLabel.leadingAnchor),
            descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: qtyOnHand.topAnchor, constant: -10)
        ]);
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            qtyOnHand.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            qtyOnHand.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor),
            qtyOnHand.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
        ]);
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            priceLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            priceLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
        ]);
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder);
    }
    
}
```

I'm also setting up the image using Alamoimagefire to scale it correctly, as I couldn't get scaling to work right by just adding the image to the UIImageView

```
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileUrl.path)
                    
let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
                    
let scaledImage = image!.af.imageAspectScaled(toFit: size)
                    
cell.imageView?.image = scaledImage
```

Any help appreciated to help me understand what would cause this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you shouldn't need to scale the image - using `.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` on your image view should work properly.

The problem you are hitting, though, is you're setting the image on the wrong image view...

```
cell.imageView?.image = scaledImage
```

should be:

```
cell.itemImageView.image = scaledImage
```

but, again, no need to scale it first.

Comment: Thank you. It helps when I set the correct property!

Comment: Regarding scaling the image, if images are huge, it can speed things up and lower your app's memory footprint to scale the image and release the original rather than letting the image view scale it on the fly.